# Shortcut to seek backward/forward in currently active media player on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, media

I'd like to create a shortcut to seek backward or forward (5s) in the currently active media player on my mac, that will work even if the application that is currently playing audio is not focused.

I know my mac does has some idea of a "currently active media player" - if I go to Spotify and play a song, then focus another app and press the "Play/Pause" button on my keyboard Spotify will be paused, if I go to a YouTube tab and play a video, the video will be paused in the same way if I have another app focused.

I believe/hope there is some kind of system event that I can dispatch somehow that both YouTube (in Chrome) and Spotify (the only two things I'm really interested in) will respect for seeking backward/forward 5s. I know they both respect the "Play/Pause" event dispatched when I click that key on my keyboard - also the "Previous Track" and "Next Track" events.

I'd be happy to use BetterTouchTool, Keyboard Maestro, Karabiner - I've installed them all in trying to achieve this :) ...or AppleScript

I've tried the following in Karabiner, but this moves forward a full track/video, instead of seeking by 5 seconds:

```
  {
    "description": "Fast forward",
    "manipulators": [
      {
        "from": {
          "key_code": "period",
          "modifiers": {
            "mandatory": ["control"]
          }
        },
        "to": [
          {
            "consumer_key_code": "fast_forward"
          }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
      }
    ]
  }
```

also tried this in Keyboard Maestro, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything - in Apple Music, Spotify, or YouTube:
[image]

My use case is I'd like to be listening to a podcast in Spotify or a video in YouTube while taking notes in another app and be able to seek around in the podcast/video without manually changing focus to Spotify e.g. every time I want to seek backward/forward.